# Why doesn't find command find the directory when run from ~?

Tags: linux, find

There is a directory under `/tmp` with the name `test_copy`.

```
$ ls /tmp/test_copy/
a.sh b.sh  

$ cd /tmp  
/tmp$ find . -name test_copy  
./test_copy
```

But if I run the following `find` command it does not return anything.

```
~/scripts$ find /tmp -name test_copy  
~/scripts$
```

Why can't `find` find the directory in the last case?

Comment: What is the result of `ls -ld /tmp`?

Comment: @xhienne: You are right! It was a symlink to another dir. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If `/tmp` is a symbolic link, `find` won't enter the directory and will just stop, finding nothing.

On the other hand, any of the following commands will work:

```
find -H /tmp -name test_copy
find /tmp/ -name test_copy
```

(the ending `/` dereferences the symlink)

Comment: This is likely to be the case on macOS in particular. On macOS, /tmp is a symlink to /private/tmp or some such.